# Working in wrong git branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I have started working on the develop branch in several files, and then realised that I should have created a new branch for it.

I have not committed the changes and the new files yet. so, how can I leave the develop branch as it was (revert?) and then copy the changes into the feature/test, which was meant to be the branch that I should be working on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't committed anything, then all you have to do is checkout a new branch `git checkout -b newbranch`, keep doing your work and then commit it on that branch.

Until you commit, your develop branch still *is* as it was.  No reverting necessary.  Also, you probably meant `reset` rather than `revert`.  A reset moves the HEAD, a revert creates a new commit that exactly undoes a given commit.

Comment: Thanks, ABMagil. Makes totally sense.

Answer (score 2):

Stash your changes:

`git stash --include-untracked`

Create a new branch and switch to it:

`git checkout -b my-new-branch`

Pop your changes:

`git stash pop`

Potentially make further changes, then when ready, add and commit all your changes as usual.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.

I have already created the new branch, though. Shall I continue without any further concerns?

Comment: In which case, you are probably fine. The stash is just belt-and-braces.

Comment: Since you are not changing the working copy you don't need to use the stash here.

Comment: @musiKk, that's not quite true. If there are conflicts/changes between the branch you are coming from and the branch you are going to, git will refuse to checkout the new branch. The stash will work around that, although you will have to fix some merge conflicts when you pop.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Ok, that's true. In my experience that's not the usual case though. I'm pretty much a "fire first" git user because git does it's darndest to not lose any data.